# Publish a VS2022 solution with 2 projects in it

Tags: visual-studio, publish, visual-studio-2022, solution

I am doing my first VS solution that I would like to publish, but I am really confused.

I have a VS2022 solution with 2 projects in it. 1 project, STM32CubePrgAPI, is the project that has all the backend stuff and other, newGUI, has the GUI stuff in it.

[image: Projects]

When I build the solution, it does create a newGUI.exe file and everything works on my computer, but I do not know how I would be able to share this, so it would work on other computers as well.

VS should have an "Publish" option, but it does not appear anywhere for me.

[image: Build menu]

[image: Right click on newGUI]

Did some Googling and asked chatGPT, but haven't found any solutions.

Tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deploying-visual-cpp-application-by-using-the-vcpp-redistributable-package?view=msvc-170), but when running the .exe file it said that it can't find the .dll files.

If you could guide me to a place, where I could find a solution, that would be perfect!
Cheers!

Comment: Publish is a concept of the .NET ecosystem. You are apparently using C++, so that feature doesn't exist. You can just copy the two files (the newGui.exe and the Stm32CubePrgApi.dll) to another computer.

Comment: There are several .dll-s and copying them doesn't work.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? This might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to make an installer for all the files needed and everything seems to be working as intended.